# Best choice for resource container?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm curious which container is the best choice to store resource data [in (data_name, pointer)-form ] to use it for a game. Fast search speed is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HashMap of type String/Pointer?

Should be a good choice at least for C++ or Java.